# How can values be appended into an Empty Array using click event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to send values into an empty array by clicking on a button.... The value of the button should be sent into the empty array....But it's not working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        var myArr = []
        $('ul#main').css({'list-style':'none'})
        $('#one').on('click', function(){
            $('ul#main').append($(this).val());
        });
        $('#two').on('click', function(){
            
            $('ul#main').append($(this).val());
        });


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
            <ul id="main"></ul>
            <br>
            <button id="remove">Delete</button>
            <button id="one" value="1">1</button>
            <button id="two" value="2">2</button>
            <button id="three" value="3">3</button>
            <button id="four" value="4">4</button>
            <button id="five" value="5">5</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: simply push the value

Comment: Would be `myArr.push($(this).val())`, also no need to make multiple click function you can do `$('#one, #two, #three')`

Comment: Thanks.... But the values are just increasing by one... I want it to show only 1 if I click on button1 and 2 if I click on button2, but it's just increasing the number by 1

Comment: Please edit your question and explain clear what you want exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change your Script like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myArr = []
        $('ul#main').css({'list-style':'none'})
        $('div button').on('click', function(){
            $('ul#main').append('<li>'+$(this).val()+'</li>');
            myArr.push($(this).val())    
        });
    });
```

i think you want add value to Array and didn't write any code for this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.html` instead of `append` If you want to `show only 1 if I click on button1 and 2 if I click on button2`

BTW, I've refactored your code to be more elegant.
Hopefully, this is helpful for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myArr = [];
        $('ul#main').css({'list-style':'none'})
        $('.number').on('click', function(){
            var number = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            $('ul#main').html(number );
            myArr.push(number);
            console.log(myArr); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
            <ul id="main"></ul>
            <br>
            <button id="remove">Delete</button>
            <button class="number" value="1">1</button>
            <button class="number" value="2">2</button>
            <button class="number" value="3">3</button>
            <button class="number" value="4">4</button>
            <button class="number" value="5">5</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? Let me know if you need any help @macaulay

Comment: Yeah.. this works, but it just appends a value... i want to convert that value to a member of an empty array

Comment: So you need to `push` that value into the array, like this `myArr.push(number);`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look @Macaulay Let me know if you need any help.